# RedirectPermanent working on local server but giving Error 500.19 on remote

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

We are trying to deploy a new ASP.NET Webapplication. To ensure compatibility with older clients who use a webservice at an URL which is not valid anymore I do the following workaround:

In the area registration:

```
context.MapRoute("Webservices_legacy_compatibility", "OldName/webservices/getVersion", new {controller = "Redirect", action = "Index"});
```

The RedirectController has this method:

```
public ActionResult Index(string name)
         {
             return RedirectPermanent("/Webservices/Update/GetLatestVersionLegacy?name=" + name);
         }
```

Now on the local Visual Studio Development Server everything works as expected, but once I deploy to the remote IIS 7.5 I get a HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error telling me, that it can't find a web.config file in \path here\OldName\web.config

Note: Access to /Webservices/Update/GetLatestVersionLegacy directly is working on the remote!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by contacting the server admin, there was another application pool assigned at OldName, once they got rid of it, the problem went away.